# CORS error only when using a react element to pixelate images, works fine when using native <img> tag

Tags: reactjs, image, cors

I am using the [react-pixelate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pixelate) library for the front end of a web app to well, pixelate images. When I try to get an image's URL from IGDB, an API that serves as a videogame database, and pixel blur it, I get a CORS error. Here is an example.

```
   <ImagePixelated
     src={https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_1080p/co2lbd.jpg}
     pixelSize={5}
     width={450}
     height={450}
   />
```

This raises the following error:

```
Access to image at 'https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co1rgi.jpg' (redirected from 'http://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/co1rgi.jpg') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Which would make sense if this is a cors error server-side, but when I just put the url in an <img> tag instead...

```
<img src={'https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_1080p/co2lbd.jpg'}
```

It fetches the images from IGDB with no problem. Does this have to do with the react-pixelate library?

Comment: That library sets `crossorigin` [attribute on the img tag](https://github.com/tonynguyenit18/react-pixelate/blob/master/src/ImagePixelated/index.tsx#L40) it generates forcing CORS. When  you manually create the img tag, you are not specifying it and hence CORS is not checked.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I tried setting ```crossorigin={'anonymous'}``` on the ```ImagePixelated``` element but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the pixelated image without forcing CORS? @MatJ